# Error when basing my DbContext on ApplicationDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

After a bit of reading, it seems like a quite common scenario for people to base a database context on the ApplicationDbContext (instead of the DbContext) so you can include AspNetUsers in collections etc.

However, when i change it, 'base' shows an error in VS2015, stating that

> 'ApplicationDbContext' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument

Any idea why this is, and if i actually need that 'base' attribute added?

```
public class MyWebsiteContext : ApplicationDbContext
{
    public MyWebsiteContext() : base("MyWebsiteContext")
    {

    }

various DbSets

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't ApplicationDbContext an automatically generated class that inherits from DbContext? I believe its constructor does not take a parameter, and your error message implies that. In order to correct this issue you only need change this line:

```
public MyWebsiteContext() : base("MyWebsiteContext")
```

To this:

```
public MyWebsiteContext() : base()
```